# Not able to understand a part of a Java Map interface tut on docs.oracle

Tags: java, hashmap

The text I did not understood was:

> In addition to its (Map interface's) obvious use of dumping one Map into another, it has
>   a second, more subtle use. Suppose a Map is used to represent a
>   collection of attribute-value pairs; the putAll operation, in
>   combination with the Map conversion constructor, provides a neat way
>   to implement attribute map creation with default values. The following
>   is a static factory method that demonstrates this technique.

```
  static <K, V> Map<K, V> newAttributeMap(Map<K, V>defaults, Map<K, V> overrides) {
      Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<K, V>(defaults);
      result.putAll(overrides);
      return result;
  }
```

You can find it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) under title "Map Interface Bulk Operations"

Comment: You have default attribute value pairs, and you want to override the default settings with the user-defined settings. What is so hard to understand?

Comment: well they named the variable override, thats all, which I felt insuffucient to understand what goes with keys, it did not striked things in my mind, and text is confusing, though the concept is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `putAll()` method to add elements of another map to this map. It is named `overrides` in this case to tell you that, it overrides a key-value pair already present in `defaults`. Ie if defaults contain a key value pair A->B, and in overrides comes A->C, resulting map will contain only A->C.

or if defaults contains A->B and overrides contains D->E, such that A.equals(D), then resulting map will have only A(or D as both are equal)->E .

The static method mentioned returns a new `Map` which combines `defaults` with `overrides`(having priority) and returns it. For that method used `Map map =  new HashMap(defaults)`; consturctor in combination with `putAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

It says that you can load default key value pairs and override only a selected subset (or even all of them if you choose) of them.

For example you want to create a map with the user supplied values for the keys. Let us say, there are safe defaults for some or all of the keys that the user does not need to supply the values for all the keys.

So you create a map with the defaults and the caller provides only those that he wants to override. In this case you will want to overwrite the values of those keys supplied by the caller. Instead of doing it one by one you use the above mechanism to achieve this in a seemingly single call.

Comment: +1 for "override **only a selected subset** (or even all of them if you choose) of them"